# Getting error in eclipse for spock's @Shared annotation

Tags: eclipse, groovy, annotations, shared, spock

As a try, I created a simple groovy class in eclipse and wrote a simple spock test method.
I created one object with `@Shared` annotation and eclipse is complaining like:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Groovy:unable to resolve class Shared , unable to find class 
 for annotation
- Groovy:class Shared is not an annotation in @Shared
```

I googled a little but did not find the solution. Does anyone know why this error is occurring? Below is the sample code:

```
class SimpleSpockTestExampleSpec extends Specification {

   @Shared
   MyObject obj;

   def "length of Spock's and his friends' names"()
   {
      expect:"Replaces when-then block"
      name.size() == length

      where:
      name << ["zzzzz","xxx","yyy"]
      length << [5,6,7]
   }    
}
```

[image]

Pease ignore the line numbers in the image.

Comment: Have you imported the annotation? It should be `spock.lang.Shared`.

Comment: @Opal, Thank you very much. Works now. For java in eclipse, there is suggestions for package imports if mouse pointer is placed on the error. But for groovy, it was not showing anything. So I could not think that it was due to import problem.

Comment: Ok, adding an answer then. Please accept.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make eclipse suggest fixes for groovy cases?

Comment: Sorry, I use IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't imported appropriate package. Do you have the following statement in the code:

```
import spock.lang.Shared
```

?

Comment: Given it is a pain to pick and choose individual imports, I see no downside to simply doing the old import star trick: `import spock.lang.*`

Comment: @MarkHu, basically IDEs giving correct suggestion when it comes to import statements. Does it make any difference (and what in particular) to use star over individual?

Comment: The only difference I can see is exactly the point of the OP question: "I know this lib has this feature, so why am I getting errors...?" Don't get me on a rant about the Java culture of overly deep/sparse hierarchy.

Comment: @MarkHu I only meant any performance issues or whatever if any. Chill. Don't want to get you anywhere.

Comment: Granted, there is probably a small memory/storage savings by doing individual import statements per sub-module. My opinion is that the tradeoff is negligible in the modern era of cheap storage.